# What's the best way to replace remote.origin.url in Git?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm new to Git. Let's say Alice and Bob had been developing their project by using two Git repositories for each. And, Alice at certain times want to set up a new repository to manage their common progress. Do you think what is the best way to replace remote.origin.url in the configuration of Git?

- to replace by git config --replace
- to create new repos by git clone MAIN_REPOS
- or any?

Comment: In this situation, I usually edit `.git/config` by hand.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If they already have a remote called `origin` but want the new remote to be called `origin` then the most logical thing to do is rename or remove the existing remote called `origin` and add a new one:

```
git remote rename origin old_origin

git remote add origin url://new/url.git
```

If you don't care about the old origin you *can* just reset the URL, but you would probably want to do a full `git fetch` and a `git remote prune origin` afterwards for tidiness.

```
git config remote.origin.url url://new/url.git
```

If you have a very recent git (>1.7.0), you have a remote sub command for this:

```
git remote set-url origin url://new/url.git
```

Comment: Hi Charles,
Thank you for the giving me a concise resolution. That's very helpful.

Comment: "git remote prune origin afterwards for tidiness" what is meant by "tidiness"?

Comment: and if you don't care about the old origin and removed it, you'll need `git push --set-upstream origin master` right after it. and if you did replace an unsecured URL with SSH, you'll need to add keys to it...

Answer (score 2):

Well simply update the url in config file from .git directory.

[image: update git origin]